# Spring 4 Groovy Bean DSL AccessControlException

Tags: spring, tomcat, groovy

I'm attempting to use the Groovy DSL in Spring 4 to define our beans in a Spring MVC application.  Everything is working swimmingly in a local tomcat.

When the application is moved into a test region, also tomcat, it's failing on startup. It's failing when the importBeans method is called to bring in additional groovy DSL scripts (XML files import as expected).

When the script attempts to execute we see a stack like so:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("groovy.security.GroovyCodeSourcePermission" "/groovy/shell")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:560) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource.createCodeSource(GroovyCodeSource.java:216) ~[groovy-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource.<init>(GroovyCodeSource.java:93) ~[groovy-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:666) ~[groovy-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:647) ~[groovy-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:242) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Tracing it further shows that the initial Groovy file runs fine, loading an XML file using importBeans and then failing on the Groovy script.

The Tomcat version is 7.

I've tried adding policies to the catalina.policy file but with no luck. I'm not certain I understand a policy file very well:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/apps/myAwesomeApp/WEB-INF/classes/-" {
  permission groovy.security.GroovyCodeSourcePermission "/groovy/script";
  permission groovy.security.GroovyCodeSourcePermission "/groovy/shell";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/groovy/script", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/groovy/shell", "read";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.*";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "defineClassInPackage.*";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
};

grant codeBase "file:/groovy/shell" {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
};

grant codeBase "file:/groovy/script" {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
};

grant codeBase "file:/groovy/security/-" {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
};
```

Any thoughts on next steps?